# GWT app using UIBinder won't load properly

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

My GWT app, using UiBinder, won't load in Internet Explorer.  However, it loads just fine in Firefox, Safari, and on the iPhone.

In trying to isolate the problem, I've been stripping out parts trying to find the root cause.  I'm down to basically a Label and it still works in FF but not IE.

Here's the `EntryPoint`:

```
public class Core implements EntryPoint {

  private static Core instance;
  public static Core instance() {
    return instance;
  }

  @Override
  public void onModuleLoad() {
    instance = this;
    RootPanel container = RootPanel.get("container");
    container.add(new Label("hi"));
  }
}
```

Here's my index.jsp:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="core/core.nocache.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my appengine-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>realAppNameHere</application>
  <version>andrew</version>
  <static-files>
    <include path="**" />
    <!-- The following line requires App Engine 1.3.2 SDK -->
    <include path="**.nocache.*" expiration="0s" />
    <include path="**.cache.*" expiration="365d" />
    <exclude path="**.gwt.rpc" />
  </static-files>
  <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

And here's my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Even with this stripped-down version of everything, it still works in Firefox but not IE.  Now there aren't even any bugs thrown, not even in Firebug... it just doesn't show the label in IE, but it will show the label in FF.  I have no idea why this isn't running.

Anyone have any idea?

**Edit 3:**

Forgot the module.gwt.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='core'>
  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.AjaxLoader'/>
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>

  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>

  <entry-point class='com.company.core.client.Core'/>

  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

  <set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="SEVERE"/>
  <set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="FALSE"/>
  <set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED"/>
  <set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="DISABLED" />
</module>
```

Comment: I don't want to sound too obvious, but have you included IE in your user.agent property?? In the .gwt.xml file: <set-property name="user.agent" value="ie6"/> for example.

Comment: I hope it's something obvious.  I don't have any 'user.agent' properties set... yet it works in the other browsers like I mentioned... am I missing something?

Comment: By default, the property user.agent is set to include all browsers, so it definitely should work in IE.

Comment: Is an error happening in hosted mode as well? When you compile, does it build all of the permutations correctly?

Comment: @ColinAlworth yes, it compiles all 6 permutations without a problem.  The results in hosted mode are similar to running it on the production server... works in FF, not in IE or using the Googlebot User Agent

Comment: That error message may well be the clue - IE is throwing an exception, likely in the constructor of Button, possibly based on the button you are drawing? Is there anything special about the uibinder xml you are using to make the button? Consider posting your ui.xml file (and maybe your module file itself, if that doesnt help).

Comment: @ColinAlworth I've tried stripping everything down to the basics to isolate the problem, but still no luck.  Please see the Edit I've made to the description above.  Thanks

Comment: Surely the exception isn't still the same when you only have a RootPanel and a Label, is it? Can you add the module file too, as requested above? Also: test with someone else's machine, maybe your local copy of IE has issues - I've seen plugins that can cause strange issues in IE,  but usually nothing that stops the app from loading entirely...

Comment: I've added the .gwt.xml file.  There's no exception at all when running the stripped-down version, yet the label will still show in FF but not IE.

Comment: I have had similar problems with IE8 and UIBinder which use HTMLPanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From testing on an actual copy of IE (not the IE plugin for Firefox) we were able to see an error "console is not defined".

Turns out, this was throwing an exception in IE, preventing the page from loading:

```
public native static void log(String inString)
/*-{
  console.log(inString);
}-*/;
```

So to solve this, we'll take out that reference to `console` and replace with a cross-browser logging library, such as [GWT-Log](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/)

Answer (score 1):

Some of the things won't come up in IE6 but it will definitely get loaded. The first thing you need to see is whether you have added an User agent for IE6 as

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie6"/>
```

in your .gwt.xml file.

Next thing you need to check that whether you added an exception for localhost in your browser security settings.

If all this is done and still not working try to cleanup your project and recompile it.

Comment: Thanks, it's compiling for all the user agents.  I think I just now realized what the problem is.